# How can i append a div after 5 results gotten from the database have been appended using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append a div after every five results from this jquery code.

```
$.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
            $('#employeeList').append('<li>'+
                    '<img src="js/citybus.png" class="list-icon"/>' +
                    '<p class="line1">' + employee.firstName + '</p>' +
                    '<p class="line2">' + difference +'</p>' +
                    '<center><button onclick="setReminderClose();" id="reminderSetBox">Reminder Has Been Set</button></center>' +
                    '<button data-diff="' + hoursMin + '" data-name="' + employee.firstName + '" class="bubble" onclick="setReminder(this);">' + '<center><img src="js/bell.png" style="height:15px;width:15px;"/></center>' + '</button></li>');

        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            scroll.refresh();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Side note; for performance reasons, I would suggest you append all your html to a single string, or map the lis to an array, and append the string or array at the very end.  The less times you touch the DOM, the less it has to do all its reflows and redraws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the value of your index and if `index % 5 === 0` and then append a new `div`.

Comment: `index && index % 5 === 0` to avoid appending on 0

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by writing if else condition checking

```js
employees = [       
            { "firstName": "Fname1", "lastnName": "lastnName2"  },
            { "firstName": "Fanme2", "lastnName": "lastnName2"  },
            { "firstName": "Fname3", "lastnName": "lastnName2"  },
            { "firstName": "Fname4", "lastnName": "lastnName4"  },
            { "firstName": "Fname5", "lastnName": "lastnName5"  },
            { "firstName": "Fname6", "lastnName": "lastnName6"  },
          ];
$.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
            if(index >0 && (index + 1) % 5 == 0){
    $('#employeeList').append('<div class="green"><li>'+
                   
                    '<p class="line1">' + employee.firstName + '</p>' +
                    '<p class="line2">' + employee.lastnName +'</p>' +
                   '</li></div>');
   }else{
    $('#employeeList').append('<li>'+
                   
                    '<p class="line1">' + employee.firstName + '</p>' +
                    '<p class="line2">' + employee.lastnName +'</p>' +
                   '</li>');
   }

        });
```

```css
.green{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="employeeList">
  
</div>
```

for values

```
index >0 and (index+1) % == 0 (as index starts with '0')
```

Here is a fiddle. I have taken a test json key value pairs and implemented it.

https://jsfiddle.net/ba31s05y/14/